# Unable to use CLI Fastlane supply action with metadata for Android

Tags: android, mobile, devops, fastlane, cicd

I would like to use CLI Fastlane [supply](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/supply/) action to push an app-bundle to Play Store. Along side with other required options, i put a metadata path to declare release note so that it can be shown on the Play Store.

But it can't be executed instead it shows errors. Here's some tried CLI commands:

`fastlane run supply aab:(path to aab) track:internal json_key:(path to json key) metadata_path:"path/to/metadata" package_name:(package name)`

`fastlane run supply aab:(path to aab) track:internal json_key:(path to json key) metadata_path:"path/to/metadata/android" package_name:(package name)`

And this is how the metadata folder's described:
[image]

Finally, the error:

```
[11:06:54]: Preparing aab at path '/app-release.aab' for upload...
[11:07:19]: Updating track 'internal'...
[11:07:21]: Preparing to upload for language 'android'...

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...

➡️  http_command.rb:228:in `check_status': \e[31m[!] Invalid request\e[0m (Google::Apis::ClientError)
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/18895 [open] 7 
    2 days ago

➡️  Supply: Error 404 (Not Found) Google Api Error: Invalid request
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/18896 [closed] 4 
    16 Jun 2021

➡️  Swift: `scheme` value in Scanfile is ignored
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/19196 [open] 1 
    a week ago

and 424 more at: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/search?q=Invalid%20request&type=Issues&utf8=✓
```

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am stuck in the same

Comment: i changed directories like this: metadata/en_US/changelogs/default.txt and the terminal command parameter is metadata_path:"path/to/metadata". @PawanAcharya